# why while(rs.next()) displaying the last value in textbox

Tags: java, jdbc

i want to create an online examination project.while i click next it should display next data in textarea.but the problem is when i click on submit button it displays last data from database.
while(rs.next()) printing the last value in textbox.

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;

    import java.awt.GridLayout;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

    import java.awt.event.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.sql.*;

    import java.awt.*;

    import java.util.*;



    class Abc extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4;
    JButton b1,b2; 
    JTextArea j1,j2;
    JCheckBox c1,c2,c3,c4;
    ButtonGroup group=new ButtonGroup();

    JPanel panel2;
    Abc(){  
       j1=new JTextArea();
       j2=new JTextArea();
       c1=new JCheckBox();
       c2=new JCheckBox();
       c3=new JCheckBox();
       c4=new JCheckBox();
       j1.setEditable(false);
       c1.setSelected(false);
       c2.setSelected(false);
       c3.setSelected(false);
       c4.setSelected(false);

       group.add(c1);
       group.add(c2);
       group.add(c3);
       group.add(c4);

       Connection conn=null;
       try{  
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","java");
         System.out.println("Dc is obtained");

          }
       catch(Exception e2){
        System.out.println("conne"+e2.getMessage());
          } 
       try{
          String sq="select * from questionans";
          Statement st=conn.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sq);
          System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
          if(rs.next())
          {

           j1.setText(rs.getString(2));
           c1.setText(rs.getString(3));
           c2.setText(rs.getString(4));
           c3.setText(rs.getString(5));
           c4.setText(rs.getString(6));
          }
          System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");        
          }
          catch(Exception e1){
            System.out.println("query" +e1.getMessage());
          }
         finally{
            try {
              conn.close();
                }
          catch(Exception e)
             {
             System.out.println("close conn"+e.getMessage());     
             } 
           }








        b1=new JButton("REGISTER");
        b2=new JButton("SUBMIT"); 
        panel2=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1)); 
        panel2.add(b1);
        panel2.add(j1);
        panel2.add(c1);
        panel2.add(c2);
        panel2.add(c3);
        panel2.add(c4);
        panel2.add(b2); 

        add(panel2,BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        b1.addActionListener(this); 
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        setTitle("REGISTRATION"); 

        } 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object source=e.getSource();
            if(source==b1)
             {
              System.out.println("you pressed button b1");
              }
              else if(source==b2)
              {  

               Connection conn=null;

              try{  
                  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","java");
                  System.out.println("Dc is obtained");

                  }
             catch(Exception e4){
                    System.out.println("conne"+e4.getMessage());
                  }
               try{
                   String sq="select * from questionans";
                   Statement st=conn.createStatement();
                   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sq);
                   System.out.println("------------------------------------------");



                 while(rs.next()){

                    j1.setText(rs.getString(2));
                    c1.setText(rs.getString(3));
                    c2.setText(rs.getString(4));
                    c3.setText(rs.getString(5));
                    c4.setText(rs.getString(6));

                   }



                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");        
                   }
            catch(Exception e3){
                    System.out.println("query" +e3.getMessage());
                    }
            finally{
                    try{
                        conn.close();
                        }
            catch(Exception e6)
                   {
                    System.out.println("close conn"+e6.getMessage());     
                    } 
                  }

             String s2="";
             if(c1.isSelected()){
                     s2=s2+""+c1.getText();
                   }
             else if(c2.isSelected()){
                     s2=s2+""+c2.getText();
                   }
          else if(c3.isSelected()){
         s2=s2+""+c3.getText();
      }
   else if(c4.isSelected()){
         s2=s2+""+c4.getText();
      }


System.out.println("You clicked on "+s2);
}
    }

}


class xyz
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
   Abc a=new Abc();
   a.setSize(1000,1000) ;
   a.setVisible(true);
   a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}
```

Comment: You are repeatedly resetting the text on your UI components in the loop, so that in effect only the last value remains.

Comment: Because, that's what you told it to do `while (rs has more results) fill out the form`, so it will display the last row, because that's what was last placed in it.  May be try `if(rs.next) {...` instead...

Comment: Also, you should separate your UI from your database code and connect it via some kind of model/manager

Comment: i used if(rs.next()) but it displays just one value i want to print  all value one by one on next button click.sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your question. Anyway you loop all of data in the db table until last data and you setText in the while loop. That's mean end of the loop set last data in your text boxes.

Comment: so how i will get each value to textbox on a button click

Comment: while i press next button or submit button, i want to display next data in textarea